# Generate separate stdout/stderr files for retries of jobs on HTCondor

Tags: condor

HTCondor allows for jobs to be retried if one fails unexpectedly. However, doing so causes the standard output and standard error files from the failed job to be overwritten by the job when it is retried. This gets in the way of debugging to figure out why some jobs are failing.

Is there a way to specify that each attempt of the job should have its output?

Example configuration script and executable that demonstrates the problem:

```
Universe = vanilla
Executable = usually_crash.sh
Output = $(Cluster).$(Process).stdout
Log = $(Cluster).$(Process).log
max_retries = 100
Queue
```

usually_crash.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
random=$(($RANDOM % 10)) 
echo $random
exit $random
```

When run, this job typically fails several times, but once it succeeds all the standard output and standard error from the failed jobs are overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a good way to do this directly in HTCondor.  Assuming that there is no shared filesystem in place, and we are using HTCondor file transfer, I would change the submit file to explicitly transfer the output file into each execution attempt, and have a shell wrapper append to that file every time, e.g.

```
# crash.sub
executable = usually_crash.sh
should_transfer_files = yes
when_to_transfer_output = on_exit_or_evict
transfer_input_files = out
log = log
max_retries = 100
queue
```

And then have a shell wrapper explicitly append stdout to that file:

usually_crash.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec >> out
r=$(($RANDOM % 10))
echo $r
exit $r
```